# How get data of join other table in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I get data from the join table. I've three models User, Child, and task. User has many child and task. And Child has many task and belongs to the user. And Task belong to the user and child. I want to get user with all childs and tasks with child name. How I get child name in task object array. Mod

```
 // Parent Model
 class User < ApplicationRecord


      has_many :task, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :children
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
    end


// Child Model
class Child < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :task
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end



// Task Model
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :child
end
```

In show method

```
def show
    user = User.find(params[:id]);
    data = {
            user:user,
            childrens:user.children,
            tasks:user.task
           }

     render json:{status:'success', error:false, data:data},status: :ok
end
```

this is working and output is

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "error": false,
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "full_name": "sohail ahmad",
            "email": "sohail1@gmail.com",
            "created_at": "2020-03-10T05:41:42.045Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-10T05:41:42.045Z"
        },
        "childrens": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "user_id": 2,
                "child_name": "child 1",
                "email": "child1@gmail.com",
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:12.896Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:12.896Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "user_id": 2,
                "child_name": "child 2",
                "email": "child2@gmail.com",
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:22.910Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:22.910Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "user_id": 2,
                "child_name": "child 3",
                "email": "child3@gmail.com",
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:28.771Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:28.771Z"
            }
        ],
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "task_name": "first task",
                "date_assigned": "2020-03-10",
                "points_to_earn": 10,
                "instructions": "dummy instructions",
                "child_id": 1,
                "user_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:50:43.196Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:50:43.196Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "task_name": "first task",
                "date_assigned": "2020-03-10",
                "points_to_earn": 10,
                "instructions": "dummy instructions",
                "child_id": 4,
                "user_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:49.850Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:49.850Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "task_name": "first task",
                "date_assigned": "2020-03-10",
                "points_to_earn": 10,
                "instructions": "dummy instructions",
                "child_id": 5,
                "user_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:56.298Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:52:56.298Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "task_name": "first task",
                "date_assigned": "2020-03-10",
                "points_to_earn": 10,
                "instructions": "dummy instructions",
                "child_id": 6,
                "user_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:53:06.922Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:53:06.922Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "task_name": "first task",
                "date_assigned": "2020-03-10",
                "points_to_earn": 10,
                "instructions": "dummy instructions",
                "child_id": 6,
                "user_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:53:16.174Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:53:16.174Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How I get child name in task object array like this

```
"tasks": [
            {
                "child_name": "Chlid 1",
                "id": 1,
                "task_name": "first task",
                "date_assigned": "2020-03-10",
                "points_to_earn": 10,
                "instructions": "dummy instructions",
                "child_id": 4,
                "user_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-03-10T13:50:43.196Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-10T13:50:43.196Z"
            },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
# app/models/task.rb
def as_json(options = {})
  super.merge(child_name: child.child_name)
end
```